# replace [ ]with raw_input

Tags: python, replace

What I have

```
import random

listofLetters =['k', 'i', 'n', 'g']
x = random.choice(listofLetters)
print x 

listDash = []

print "Welcome to Gues the Letter Game!"
print " "
print "=" * 5 + "Start of Game" + "=" * 5 
print ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
print " "

maxLife = 4

print "*" * 3 + "Life Line" + "*" * 3
print "-+" * maxLife
print "$|" * maxLife
print "-+" * maxLife
print " " 


guess = raw_input("Enter your guess: ")
howmanyletter = len(guess)

if guess == x:

    print "*" * 3 + "Life Line" + "*" * 3
    print "-+" * maxLife
    print "$|" * maxLife
    print "-+" * maxLife

else:
    print "Incorrect Guess []
```

I want the `[]` to replace with guess

for example `[k]`

Comment: You are missing the closing quotes within `print "Incorrect Guess []"

Comment: Are you just asking how to interpolate a variable into a string?

Answer (score 3):

Here's some information on the Python [string.format method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

```
x=raw_input("guess? ")
print "Incorrect guess [{}].".format(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print "Incorrect Guess [%s]" % guess
```

OR

```
print "Incorrect Guess [" + guess + "]"
```

Answer (score 0):

The [raw_input()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) function returns a string, so you just have to add "guess" to the print statement:

```
print "Incorrect Guess [", guess, "]"
```